# Using Mechanize gem to return a collection of links based on their position in the DOM

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I am struggling with mechanize. I wish to "click" on a set of links which can only be identified by their position (all links within div#content) or their href.

I have tried both of these identification methods above without success.

From the documentation, I could not figure out how return a collection of links (for clicking) based on their position in the DOM, and not by attributes directly on the link.

Secondly, the [documentation](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/GUIDE_rdoc.html) suggested you can you use :href to match a partial href,

```
page = agent.get('http://foo.com/').links_with(:href => "/something")
```

but the only way I can get it to return a link is by passing a fully qualified URL, e.g

```
page = agent.get('http://foo.com/').links_with(:href => "http://foo.com/something/a")
```

This is not very usefull if i want to return a collection of links with href's

```
http://foo.com/something/a
http://foo.com/something/b
http://foo.com/something/c
etc...
```

Am I doing something wrong? do I have unrealistic expectations?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Part II
The value you pass to :href has to be an exact match by default. So the href in your example would only match `<a href="/something"></a>` and not `<a href="foo.com/something/a"></a>`

What you want to do is to pass in a regex so that it will match a substring within the href field.  Like so:

```
page = agent.get('http://foo.com/').links_with(:href => %r{/something/})
```

**edit:**
Part I
In order to get it to select links only in a link, add a nokogiri-style search method into your string.  Like this:

```
page = agent.get('http://foo.com/').search("div#content").links_with(:href => %r{/something/})    # **
```

Ok, that doesn't work because after you do `page = agent.get('http://foo.com/').search("div#content")` you get a Nokogiri object back instead of a mechanize one, so links_with won't work.  However you will be able to extract the links from the Nokogiri object using the css method.  I would suggest something like:

`page = agent.get('http://foo.com/').search("div#content").css("a")`

If that doesn't work, I'd suggest checking out http://nokogiri.org/tutorials

Comment: The documentation on mechanize could stand to be improved on this point.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any idea about the other part of my question, on returning links based on their DOM position?

Comment: Your solution to part 1 yields the following error: NoMethodError: undefined method `links_with' for []:Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet

Comment: `.links_with(:href => %r{/something/})` didn't work for me. This one did work: `.links_with(:href => /something/)`

Answer (score 2):

The nth link:

```
page.links[n-1]
```

The first 5 links:

```
page.links[0..4]
```

links with 'something' in the href:

```
page.links_with :href => /something/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get mechanize links using nokogiri nodes. See the [source code of links() method.](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Page.html)

```
# File lib/mechanize/page.rb, line 352
def links
  @links ||= %w{ a area }.map do |tag|
    search(tag).map do |node|
      Link.new(node, @mech, self)
    end
  end.flatten
end
```

So that means:

```
the_links= page.search("valid_selector").map do |node|
  Mechanize::Page::Link.new(node, agent, page)
end
```

This will give you the useful href, text and uri methods.

Comment: Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError: unexpected '@href' after '[#<Nokogiri::CSS::Node: